# unable to authenticate to postgresql via psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

Hi guys I know this question has been asked many times but I've been searching through stackoverflow for hours and looking at similar issues but I haven't been able to figure out why I keep getting the authentication issue. Below is how I'm trying to connect to postgres via psycopg2

```
import psycopg2
psycopg2.connect("dbname=test0 user=doug host=localhost password=testpassword123 port=5432")
```

After running `python3 test.py` I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    psycopg2.connect("dbname=test0 user=doug host=localhost password=testpassword123 port=5432")
  File "/home/doug/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "doug"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "doug"
```

I've checked that the user `doug` exists and has superuser privileges:

```
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 doug      | Superuser                                                  | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

I've created the user doug with the following:

```
CREATE USER doug WITH PASSWORD 'testpassword123';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test0 to doug;
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you. Also I've checked and confirmed that postgresql is running on port 5432.

Comment: What version of Postgres? What version of psycopg2? What does the Postgres log show?  Can you log in using `psql`? Add answers as update to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the password for the user `doug` is different than `testpassword123`. Based off the error message, PostgreSQL is attempting to authenticate the credentials.